# https to http redirection not working

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I am trying to achieve following redirect.
https://abc.com to http://www.abc.com

I have already used following redirect rule, which works fine for http non-www to http www redirect, but it is not working for https non-www to http www redirect.

```
<rule name="HttpsTOHttpRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^https://abc.com" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.abc.com{REQUEST_URI}" />
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule to remove `www` may work but you can optimize it.

To get what you want you will need those 2 rules:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Add www if missing">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

The first rule redirects using `http` if it was a `https` request (using a back reference to keep the original url: `{R:0}`).

The second rule appends `www` when it is missing (using 2 back references to keep the original url: `{R:0}` and `{C:0}`).